# How to reposition rowList dropdown in jqgrid's pager?

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to re-position the rowList dropdown (defined as `rowList:[10,20,30]`) to the left side of the pager rather than the default right-hand side position. How is that achieved?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not possible with the API. If you really must do this, try something like the following:

For a pager defined like so,

```
<div id="grid_pager"></div>
```

Add this to your [`gridComplete` event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents):

```
$(' #grid_pager_center tr').prepend(  $(' #grid_pager_center td:last') );
```